# How to solve the "Connection Unsuccessful" when trying to connect iPhone to Mac Book Pro via bluetooth?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, bluetooth

MacBook Pro summer 2015 edition. Bluetooth is enabled. iPhone 6 plus and iPhone 7 plus bluetooth is enabled.

When trying to connect from MBP to the iPhone after tapping 'Pair' on the iPhone with the message

```
Waiting for "iPhone" to accept pairing
```

MBP is saying that the iPhone is connected but after a second or two the connection gets dropped.

Trying to connect to the MBP from the iPhone gives a message on the iPhone

```
Connection Unsuccessful
"MBP-Hostname" is not supported
<<Forget Device>>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What are you expecting to use the Bluetooth connection for? - Modern iPhones do not use the old style bluetooth pairing for functionality such as internet sharing or voice dialing from the MacBook Pro. Instead make sure you're logged in on the same apple-id on both devices, that both devices are on the same WiFi and that Bluetooth is enabled on both devices.

Comment: I would like to use Mac's keyboard as an external keyboard on the iPhone, something I was able to do with Logitech's K480 keyboard https://secure.logitech.com/en-ch/product/multi-device-keyboard-k480

Answer (score 1):

Using the Mac's keyboard as an external keyboard for the iPhone over Bluetooth is, unforunately, not supported.

You would need third party software on the Mac and special apps that support this third part software for something like that to work. I don't know of any such software in existence today.

Answer (score 1):

**Apple prevents bluetooth pairing** between its most recent Macs and iPhones.
**The current profusion of sharing options** between Macs and iOS devices (continuity, airdrop, iCloud, wifi, iMessage etc.), combined to **newer bt protocols no longer requiring pairing**, would be the reasoning behind this design choice of forced obsolescence. https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-7722

> Unfortunately the error message only states "Pairing unsuccessful - Mac is not supported" - whereas this is actually a "feature" and not an "error". ➜ Hopefully Apple will **improve the pairing error message** and avoid future users wasting time trying usual fixes (iphone restart, PRAM resets etc...) in vain.