# Unable to pair iPhone 13 mini to Mac Mini

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, mac-mini

I have an iPhone 13 mini running 16.3.1
I recently purchased a Mac Mini (Apple M2) updated to 13.2.1.
I transferred from my iMac to Mac Mini and have been setting it up and transferred my operations to this as my primary computer. This is using a Bluetooth keyboard & mouse.

I wanted to setup Continuity camera, but without much success so I took one step back to setup Bluetooth first.

The Mac Mini sees the iPhone 13 in nearby devices.

The iPhone 13 mini sees the Mac Mini in nearby devices.

After many failed attempts I eventually got both to see the same code number and paired, although they show as Not connected.

When I try to connect I get a message "Connection Unsuccessful the Mac Mini is not supported" and the only option is to "Forget Device".

One potential complication - clicking on the ⓘ on the Mac Mini shows 16.3.0 for the iPhone.

I have Handoff & Continuity Camera enabled on the iPhone.

I can successfully AirDrop from the iPhone 13 to Mac Mini.

Any idea what might be going on to hinder the pairing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a design choice apparently by Apple on recent systems. For more information https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/462503/260625.

Comment: I think a better answer is “traditional BT pairing is not needed as Apple creates this link for you through the `awdl` interface.”

Comment: Should you seek even  higher greatness status for your answer, I suggest you add more explanations regarding the awdl interface role and relevance in the context, similarly with the "traditions" of BlueTooth as they are not common knowledge for most (< 4.0?). This could be posted as a proper answer in its fully glory, rather than as a mere comment. My 2 cents.

Comment: The interfaces are listed in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/332194/119271).  The (rhetorical) question that should be asked is why does someone need a regular BT connection when there’s AirDrop, Handoff, Continuity, etc.

Comment: @ Allan: cf. link in original answer.